# Mutability in Swift

Tags: swift, immutability

Swift will create either a mutable or an immutable collection depending on whether you use `var` or `let`. This got me interested - the compiler probably has to interfere and initialize objects of different classes in each case.

How does it work? Can I use the same mechanism with my code? Teach Swift to do the same trick for my classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to teach. Class instances are always mutable regardless of whether you say `var` or `let`.

Collections are structs; the rules you're describing are for structs, which are a different animal. They are almost classes in Swift, but not quite; you've put your finger on a key difference. Any struct you make will behave the same way: it will be immutable through a reference declared `let`.

Comment: "the compiler probably has to interfere and initialize objects of different classes in each case." Nope, it really is all about the declaration.

Comment: Are Arrays really structs? The complicated semantics where they can have their elements modified but not their length and they may or may not share state depending on what operations you do to them don't sound struct-like.

Comment: @Chuck: `Array` is a struct.

Comment: @matt What if I wanted to make my own collection with compiler-determined mutability?